# How to use a variable within a call to #include virtual on a webpage?

Tags: asp.net, include

I have an `#include virtual` of the following sort :

```
<!--#include virtual="/cgi-bin/mywebsite/myscript.pl?param1=value1&param2=value2" -->
```

I want `value2` in the line above to assume the value of the `myvar` variable.

I tried to no avail after checking online :

```
<!--#include virtual="/cgi-bin/mywebsite/myscript.pl?param1=value1&param2=${myvar}" -->
```

What is the correct syntax for this one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that, because the included file is processed and added before any scripts are executed.

What you *can* do is include an `asp` file that will determine at the time it is included what text to insert.

Comment: Thank you for that. Even if the variable is already initialized and has a value ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a *variable* until the file and its includes have been loaded and the result executed using the script processor.

Comment: OK I'll start another thread on how to pass parameters to an #exec cgi perl script.